# F# - How to position Function that calls function

Tags: f#

I have some code, 3 functions

`ParseTemplate`, `ParseTemplates` -> These two can be combined into one and will have to be to make this work I think.
And
`loadTemplate`

```
let ParseTemplate (template: Match) =
    let templateName = template.Groups.[1] |> string
    loadTemplate templateName

let ParseTemplates (string: string) =
    Regex.Replace(string, "\[tpl\:(.*?)\]", MatchEvaluator ParseTemplate)

let rec loadTemplate templateName =
        templateName
        |> getTemplateFilePath
        |> File.ReadAllText
        |> ParseVariables
        |> ParseArrays
        |> ParseLanguageVariablesWithReplacements
        |> ParseSimpleLanguageVariables
        |> ParseTemplates
```

The problem is where to position these in the file/how to structure them differently, because as it is there's always a function calling a function below it (and therefore is not defined).

In this case

I like the `loadTemplate` function as it exists - it's very clean and readable and I'd rather avoid using lambda functions inside of it if possible. The problem is it calls `ParseTemplates` which can then call `loadTemplate` recursively.

Best way to approach?

Comment: I assume what you're asking is how to get the three functions to know about each other. Use the `rec` [keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/recursive-functions-the-rec-keyword) on the first, and the `and` keyword instead of the `let` keyword on the two next.

Comment: Yup, love it when it's just a simple gap in knowledge of language features!